# Leafletjs error: Invalid GeoJSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to populate a point layer using leafletjs but I keep getting an invalid GeoJSON object error.  I have run the GeoJSON object I'm using through a linter and it comes back as valid.  I'm a populating the coordinated property using an ajax call.  If I put in some hard coded coordinates the points are populated just fine.  Why am I getting this error when the object appears to be valid GeoJSON and why does it only happen when I populate the coordinates through ajax?

My ajax call:

```
$.get("/controller/twitter_get.php", function(data){
    var tweetData = $.parseJSON(data);
    tweetLocations = {
"type": "MultiPoint",
"coordinates": tweetData
    };
```

});

That call returns data like this:

```
"[[-81.569531,41.4598968],[-81.48370709,41.52049303],[-81.4773,41.5221]]"
```

The resulting GeoJSON object is:

```
{
"type": "MultiPoint",
"coordinates": [
[
  -81.569531,
  41.4598968
],
[
  -81.48370709,
  41.52049303
],
[
  -81.4773,
  41.5221
],
[
  -81.4773,
  41.5221
],
[
  -81.4773,
  41.5221
]]}
```

Comment: Your geojson looks valid. Can you show the code where you add the data to a leaflet layer?

Comment: @Krxldfx Here is the code for the leaflet layer: `var tweets = L.geoJson(tweetLocations, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var twitterIcon = L.Icon.extend({
            options: {
                iconSize: [27, 27],
                iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                popupAnchor: [1, -24],
                iconUrl: 'twitter-logo-transparent-small.png'
            }
        });
        var icon = new twitterIcon();
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: icon
        })
    }
});`

Comment: I assume you don't use a callback for your ajax request? You probably create the layer before the asynchronous request assigns the data to your variable, so leaflet says it's invalid geojson. See e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163535/leaflet-layer-control-not-visible for hints on using ajax request with leaflet layers.

Comment: @Krxldfx That fixed my issues. Thanks!